# Do the "follow TCP stream" option in wireshark include duplicate packets?

Tags: linux, wireshark

When I tried to follow a TCP stream in wireshark, I found some duplicate packets. I wanted to know whether wireshark excludes duplicate(or retransmission) TCP packets from the "follow TCP stream" output.

If not, how to avoid displaying duplicate packets when I follow a TCP stream? 
I used Wireshark version 1.2.7

I wanted to differentiate whether the actual data I passed is duplicated , or what I see is the retransmission packet of TCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent versions of Wireshark follow the TCP specification correctly, i.e. retransmitted packets with the same TCP sequence number only show up once (with the first one where the checksum works being the one that takes precedence).

The most likely thing is that your application is sending the data more than once, and so Wireshark is correctly showing it twice.

Comment: Yes. I was duplicate in application data packet. By the way I found this "editcap -d" to eliminate TCP duplicates.